# sql: finding all rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an app with articles. Each article is available in different languages: english (`en`), deutch (`de`) and japanese (`jp`).

Articles translations are stored in the `translation` table:

| locale | article_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| en | 2 | hello |
| de | 2 | hallo |
| ja | 2 | こんにちは |
| en | 3 | world |
| de | 3 | welt |
| en | 4 | foo |

Some of these articles translations are missing (ex: article `3`  is not available in japanese).

I want every article to be available in every locales (`en`, `jp` and `de`).

So I need a sql query that will return the missing translations, such as:

| locale | article_id |
| --- | --- |
| ja | 3 |
| de | 4 |
| ja | 4 |

Comment: **NB**: for more context, I am using the [mobility gem](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) and I would like to translate with google translate every translatable with missing translations.

Comment: **NB2**: when dealing with sql queries, I often struggle finding the words describing my use case, and consequently I can't find relevant information. Do you have advice I could use ?

Comment: Doesn't seem difficult to write a query for it. However, I still fail to understand the details. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and desired results? My naive understanding of the question suggests that you just want `SELECT translatable_id FROM yourtable WHERE locale IS NULL;` but I would imagine the requirement is more complex than that.

Comment: Define '...missing translations.' . Add information as update to question.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: It seems you want where there's at least one `translatable_id` that is not `null`, and want everyone with the same ID that is? You're going to need to clarify your question however.

Comment: You are attempting to show where a translatable_id doesn't have a particular local?  Does this question help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933273/sql-easiest-way-to-show-missing-data.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it makes it more comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE:

```
CREATE TABLE public.translate (
    locale character varying,
    translatable_id integer
);

INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('en', 2);
INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('de', 2);
INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('ja', 2);
INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('en', 3);
INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('de', 3);
INSERT INTO public.translate VALUES ('en', 4);


WITH dist AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id.locale,
        t.translatable_id
    FROM
        translate AS id,
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
                translatable_id
            FROM
                translate) AS t
)
SELECT
    dist.locale, dist.translatable_id
FROM
    dist
    LEFT JOIN translate ON dist.translatable_id = translate.translatable_id
        AND dist.locale = translate.locale
WHERE
    translate.locale IS NULL;

locale | translatable_id 
--------+-----------------
 ja     |               3
 de     |               4
 ja     |               4
```